python logic? relay not activating when condition is met
When I push the off switch offSwitch boolean changes from 1 to 0 so controller is seeing the switch and offRelay should activate. My logic is most definitely the problem lol. This is a learning project for me on a Pi Pico.
When I physically change and force offRelay(1) before #main the relay activates? So my Pins are correct I'm just not sure I'm going about this the right way.
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep
#var's pinouts
offRelay = Pin(18,Pin.OUT)
offSwitch = Pin(2,Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
leadRelay = Pin(19,Pin.OUT)            
leadFloat = Pin(6, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
lagFloat = Pin(10, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
lagRelay = Pin(20, Pin.OUT)
hwwFloat = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
hwwRelay = Pin(21, Pin.OUT)
offLight = Pin(3, Pin.OUT)
pumpOneLight = Pin(7, Pin.OUT)
pumpTwoLight = Pin(11, Pin.OUT)
hwwLight = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)

#Functions




#main code
while offSwitch == 1:
  if offSwitch == 0:
   offRelay(1)
  if offSwitch(0) and leadFloat(0):
   leadRelay(1)
   offLight(1)
   pumpOneLight(1)
  if offSwitch(0) and leadFloat(0) and lagFloat(0):
   lagRelay(1)
   pumpTwoLight(1)
  if hwwFloat == 0:
   hwwRelay(1)
   hwwLight(1)

#Test activity
print(offSwitch.value(),"off float")
print(offRelay.value(), "off relay")
print(leadFloat.value(), "lead float")
print(leadRelay.value(), "lead relay")
print(offLight.value(), "off float led light")
print(lagFloat.value(), "lag float")
print(lagRelay.value(), "lag relay")
print(pumpTwoLight.value(), "pump 2 led light")
print(hwwFloat.value(), "hww float")
print(hwwRelay.value(), "hww relay")



Should you be reading those input values with .value() instead of comparing them to integers (or calling them with a value)?

You are trying to compare Pin type to an int type. You are also attempting to call a Pin object with an int argument.
Revised code here:
from machine import Pin
from time import sleep
#var's pinouts
offRelay = Pin(18,Pin.OUT)
offSwitch = Pin(2,Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
leadRelay = Pin(19,Pin.OUT)            
leadFloat = Pin(6, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
lagFloat = Pin(10, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
lagRelay = Pin(20, Pin.OUT)
hwwFloat = Pin(14, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
hwwRelay = Pin(21, Pin.OUT)
offLight = Pin(3, Pin.OUT)
pumpOneLight = Pin(7, Pin.OUT)
pumpTwoLight = Pin(11, Pin.OUT)
hwwLight = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)

#Functions

#main code
while offSwitch.value() == 1:
  if offSwitch.value() == 0:
   offRelay.value(1)
  if offSwitch.value(0) and leadFloat.value(0):
   leadRelay.value(1)
   offLight.value(1)
   pumpOneLight.value(1)
  if offSwitch.value(0) and leadFloat.value(0) and lagFloat.value(0):
   lagRelay.value(1)
   pumpTwoLight.value(1)
  if hwwFloat.value() == 0:
   hwwRelay.value(1)
   hwwLight.value(1)

#Test activity
print(offSwitch.value(),"off float")
print(offRelay.value(), "off relay")
print(leadFloat.value(), "lead float")
print(leadRelay.value(), "lead relay")
print(offLight.value(), "off float led light")
print(lagFloat.value(), "lag float")
print(lagRelay.value(), "lag relay")
print(pumpTwoLight.value(), "pump 2 led light")
print(hwwFloat.value(), "hww float")
print(hwwRelay.value(), "hww relay")

I’m not entirely sure when you are trying to read a value or when you are trying to set a value. This code might not work, but at least it won’t do anything MicroPython disallows.

Based on the comment and answer:
if offSwitch.value() == False:
   offRelay.value(True)
else:
    offRelay.value(False)

is how I got the relay to go on and off.
